# Raw type 'Bool' is not expressible by any literal

Tags: swift, enums, rawrepresentable

I want to have my enums easily compatible with `@IBInspectable`, so for the sake of simplicity, I tried to have it representable with type `Bool`:

```
enum TopBarStyle: Bool {
    case darkOnLight
    case lightOnDark
}
```

But Xcode is giving me:

> Raw type 'Bool' is not expressible by any literal

That's strange, as `true` and `false` seem to be perfect candidates for expressibility by literals.

I've also tried to add `RawRepresentable` conformance to type Bool with:

```
extension Bool: RawRepresentable {
    public init?(rawValue: Bool) {
        self = rawValue
    }
    public var rawValue: Bool {
        get { return self }
    }
}
```

But it didn't solve the error.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID149: *"Raw values can be strings, characters, or any of the integer or floating-point number types.*

Comment: You could achieve the same effect by adding a computed `var boolValue` on the enum.

Comment: To add to @MartinR's comment, `true` and `false` aren't literals; they're closer to constants (constants whose names are reserved by the compiler). A literal is something that the compiler has some magic to convert to an internal value. There is no magic necessary to make sense of `true` and `false`, as they're keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is necessary. You can just make a normal enum and then switch over its cases. Also, it's not clear at all what `TopBarStyle(rawValue: true)` would mean if this could be achieved.

I would either use `var darkOnLight: Bool`, or `enum TopBarStyle { /*cases*/ }` and switch over the cases as necessary.

Answer (score 16):

Swift 3 natively defines those nine literal representations:

- ExpressibleByNilLiteral (`nil`)
- ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral (`false`)
- ExpressibleByArrayLiteral (`[]`)
- ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral (`[:]`)
- ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral (`0`)
- ExpressibleByFloatLiteral (`0.0`)
- ExpressibleByUnicodeScalarLiteral (`"\u{0}"`)
- ExpressibleByExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral (`"\u{0}"`)
- ExpressibleByStringLiteral (`""`)

But `enum` raw representation [will apparently only accept natively](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID149) the subset of those representions that start with a digit (`0`-`9`), a sign (`-`, `+`) or a quote (`"`): the last five protocols of above list.

In my opinion, the error message should have been more specific. Maybe something explicit like that would have been nice:

> *Raw type 'Bool' is not expressible by any numeric or quoted-string literal*

Extending Bool to conform to one of those protocols is still possible, for example:

```
extension Bool: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    public init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self = value != 0
    }
}
```

And after doing so, this code now builds fine:

```
enum TopBarStyle: Bool {
    case darkOnLight
    case lightOnDark
}

@IBInspectable var style = TopBarStyle(rawValue: false)!
```

Answer (score 14):

my solution on swift 3

```
enum DataType: RawRepresentable {
    case given
    case received

    typealias RawValue = Bool
    var rawValue: RawValue {
        return self == .given ? true : false
    }
    init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        self = rawValue == true ? .given : .received
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So `extension Bool: RawRepresentable` + `enum DataType: Bool` doesn't work, but a direct `enum DataType: RawRepresentable` will work.

Comment: Note that the `typealias` is not needed here.

Comment: Please note that this line (return self == .given ? true : false) will cause recursion. so please use switch case instead.

Comment: the problem is Codable won't work properly with such structure

Answer (score 7):

Simplify your life:

```
enum TopBarStyle {
    case darkOnLight
    case lightOnDark

    var bool: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .darkOnLight:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Use as usual:

```
    var current = TopBarStyle.darkOnLight

    if current.bool {
        // do this
    } else {
        // do that
    }
```

You can extend cases to more but they are not reversible since its an N : 2 matrix

Comment: That doesn't make it compatible with `@IBInspectable`. So in that regard, the accepted answer is more helpful.

Comment: Why you want to use an Extra '.bool' when swift RawRepresentable provides you the flexibility.

Comment: I recreated this to make it easier for me to access certain predefined SCNVector3 values. Super good answer!

Comment: Is it possible to print out the variable name that is equal to true? In this case print `darkOnLight` because it's the variable with the true boolean. Would the `Mirror` type help in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Working example in Swift 5:

```
public enum MyBoolEnum: CaseIterable, RawRepresentable {

    case yes
    case no

    public init?(rawValue: Bool) {
        self = rawValue ? .yes : .no
    }

    public var rawValue: RawValue {
        switch self {
        case .yes:
            return true
        case .no:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```