# Declaring an enum to change color used in app for different type of users

Tags: ios, swift, enums, uicolor

I'm developing an app which has two type of user (Admin, Normal User). Color of UITabBar and NavigationBar changes according to user type. 
How I declare colors;

```
struct Color{
struct NavigationBar{
    static let tintColor =  UIColor(red:0.01, green:0.54, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0)
    static let textColor = UIColor.white
}
```

How I call;

```
tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = Color.TabBar.tintColor
```

I can write an If statement in where I call "Color.TabBar" and choose right color but I'm wondering If I can do it with enum. Like below code;

```
struct Color{
struct NavigationBar{
    enum tintColor{
        case admin
        case user
        var color: UIColor{
            switch self {
            case .admin:
                return UIColor(red:0.01, green:0.54, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0)
            case .user:
                return UIColor(red:0.01, green:0.54, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0)
            default:
                return UIColor(red:0.01, green:0.54, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0)
            }
        }
    }
    //static let tintColor =  UIColor(red:0.01, green:0.54, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0)
    static let textColor = UIColor.white
}
```

I find below article but I think this does not related with my problem. So my question is that how can I write that kind of enum?

[How can I make a Swift enum with UIColor value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112879/how-can-i-make-a-swift-enum-with-uicolor-value)

Comment: Yes, you can have a style enum, and make switches from it to extract colors, images, or other UI components. It is in my opinion the cleanest way to make apps with separate themes, as the logic is easily separated from the rest, and easily testable.

But again, what is your exact question?

Comment: How can I write that kind of enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is not possible. Enum may not be a class, only a generic type, a structure.

But it is usually not what you want as when you will have many of these values you will have a mess anyway. For instance at some point you will have a button background color, border color and text color. Then waht do you expect your result to be like:

```
button.backgroundColor = UIButton.backgroundColor
button.layer.borderColor = UIButton.borderColor.cgColor
button.label.textColor = UIButton.textColor
```

And now having 3 enums for a single component... It is a solution but I think it is a bad one...

I suggest you rather create a static class and have it like so:

```
class UserApperance {
    static var userType: UserType = .admin

    static var navigationTintColor: UIColor {
        switch userType {
            case .admin: ...
            case .user: ...
        }
    }

}
```

So all you will do in the code is again

```
tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = UserApperance.navigationTintColor
```

And when you want to group them you can use nesting:

```
class UserApperance {
    static var userType: UserType = .admin

    class NavigationBar {
        static var tintColor: UIColor {
            switch UserApperance.userType {
                case .admin: ...
                case .user: ...
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Where the result is now nicer:

```
tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = UserApperance.NavigationBar.tintColor
```

In my opinion this is the nicest way and with really hard situations like white-label applications you can really play around with nesting and do it per screen and even have code like:

```
let appearance =  UserAppearance.thisScreenName
titleLabel.textColor = appearance.title.textColor
titleLabel.font = appearance.title.font
```

Bot to mention you can generalize some things and even have usage as

```
UserAppearance.thisScreenName.title.configure(label: titleLabel)
```

Which may set all the property of your UI element...

But if you really, really badly want to have this you can still use something like strings as colors or pretty much any primitive...

You can create extensions like

```
extension UIView {

    var backgroundColorString: String? {
        set {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: newValue)
        }
        get {
            return self.backgroundColor.toHexString()
        }
    }

}
```

Then you obviously use this property to set the color directly from enumeration. But I discourage you to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The way you implement is correct, but you need to keep user type as global.

This is how it needs to be done;

```
enum tintColor{
    case admin
    case user
    var tabbarColor: UIColor{
        switch self {
        case .admin:
            return UIColor(red:0.01, green:0.54, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0)
        case .user:
            return UIColor(red:0.01, green:0.54, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0)
        default:
            return UIColor(red:0.01, green:0.54, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0)
        }
    }
}

static var user = tintColor.user
user.tabbarColor // this returns .user color
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you have millions way of dealing with this, but remember that you have three elements :

**A user role variable**. Surely not only related to the UI, and thus defined somewhere like `enum UserRole { case user, admin }`. Let's say that you retrieve this information somewhere, and that you inject this variable in your view controllers.

**A way to convert this user role into styles**. For example, by using some static functions:

```
struct Styles {
    struct NavigationBar {
        static func barColor(from userRole:UserRole) -> UIColor {
            switch userRole {
            case .user: return UIColor.blue
            case .admin: return UIColor.blue
            }
        }

        static barFont(from userRole:UserRole) -> UIFont {
            //... do the swith thing again
        }
    }
}
```

Another but related approach would be, if you start having more styles, you can also create a struct instance from an userRole variable.

```
struct Styles {
    struct NavigationBar {
        let color:UIColor
        let font:UIFont

        init(userRole:UserRole) {
            switch userRole {
            case .admin:
                color = .red
                font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
            case .user:
                color = .blue
                font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally, from your controller**, just call the adequate method to retrieve the style. Here is an exemple using a simple dependency injection :

```
let userRole:UserRole

init(userRole:UserRole) {
    self.userRole = userRole
    super.init()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) is not implemented") }

override func viewDidload() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = Styles.NavigationBar.barColor(from: userRole)
}
```

Comment: In your answer I need to get userRole for every controller. Is there a way to make is instance. I mean I want to declare userRole in one view controller and every  other viewcontorller I just want to call "Styles.NavigationBar.barColor" ?

Comment: What you describe is accessing a global variable. Usually it's made by having a singleton object (e.g. in your Styles struct, you would have a line like ```static var navigationBarStyle = Style.NavigationBar(userRole: .user)```), but it's good practice to inject it anyway in your view controllers.